# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ..)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT values per DATE and then add them all together. Here is my main count code:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(track.ip) AS tracker
FROM   user,
       track
WHERE  track.user = $user
GROUP  BY $user
ORDER  BY tracker
LIMIT  1
```

My database name is datein and the way it inputs the date and time that the INSERT was done. Here is the code:

```
      Database column :   datein

      Database insert looks like :    2013-11-8 11:17:23
```

I believe it should look something similar to this code:

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(DISTINCT track.user) AS tracker
FROM   user,
       track
WHERE  track.user = $user
       AND track.datein >= NOW() - INTERVAL BEGINNING DAY
GROUP  BY $user
ORDER  BY tracker
LIMIT  1
```

It should look something similar to that code above, but there should be a way to select it. How can I SELECT COUNT DISTINCT values per date?

Comment: Can you give sample data and desired results?

Comment: I can count the distinct but I cannot... count date intervals...

Comment: What would be the intervals from NOW and the beginning of my database.

Comment: It was suppose to be selected by ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a result set with two columns: count of distinct users, date. I can't figure out your `FROM` clause so I'll skip over that part.

Let's start with a result set containing user and date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user, 
                TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(track.datein, '%Y-%m-%d')) datein
  FROM whatever
 WHERE whatever
   AND whatever
```

That crushes down the datetime values to simple dates, and gives us a user/date result set with distinct rows.

Next, we summarize it.

```
SELECT count(*) AS tracker
       datein
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT user, 
                    TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(track.datein, '%Y-%m-%d')) datein
      FROM whatever
     WHERE whatever
       AND whatever
  ) AS a
  GROUP BY datein
```

That should give you the result set you need.

Answer (score 0):

From you comments i guess you need to compare the datein from the oldest date in databasemif this you want you can do so by using `MIN` function with a combination of `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(DISTINCT track.user) AS tracker
FROM   user,
       track
GROUP  BY $user
HAVING track.user = $user
       AND track.datein >= MIN(datein)
ORDER  BY tracker
LIMIT  1
```